# Laravel importer giving Undefined index exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a Laravel importer with GUI.
So, i have a "ParseImport" function:

```
public function parseImport(CsvImportRequest $request)
    {

        $path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();

        if ($request->has('header')) {
            $data = Excel::toArray([],request()->file('csv_file'))[0];
        } else {
            $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
        }

        if (count($data) > 0) {
            if ($request->has('header')) {
                $csv_header_fields = [];
                foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
                    $csv_header_fields[] = $key;
                }
            }
            $csv_data = array_slice($data, 0, 2);

            $csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
                'csv_filename' => $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
                'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
                'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
            ]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return view('import_fields', compact( 'csv_header_fields', 'csv_data', 'csv_data_file'));

    }
```

And a "ProcessImport":

```
public function processImport(Request $request)
    {
        $data = CsvData::find($request->csv_data_file_id);
        $csv_data = json_decode($data->csv_data, true);
        foreach ($csv_data as $row) {
            $item = new Item();
            var_dump($item);
            foreach (config('app.db_fields') as $index => $field) {
                if ($data->csv_header) {
                    $item->$field = $row[$request->fields[$field]];
                } else {
                    $item->$field = $row[$request->fields[$index]];
                }
            }
            $item->save();
        }

        return view('import_success');
    }
```

When uploading my csv file:

[image]

and choose matching fields in my GUI, from my import_fields.blade.php:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('import_process') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="csv_data_file_id" value="{{ $csv_data_file->id }}" />

    <table class="table">
        @if (isset($csv_header_fields))
            <tr>
                @foreach ($csv_header_fields as $csv_header_field)
                    <th>{{ $csv_header_field }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endif
        @foreach ($csv_data as $row)
            <tr>
                @foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                    <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
            @foreach ($csv_data[0] as $key => $value)
                <td>
                    <select name="fields[{{ $key }}]">
                        @foreach (config('app.db_fields') as $db_field)
                            <option value="{{ (\Request::has('header')) ? $db_field : $loop->index }}"
                                    @if ($key === $db_field) selected @endif>{{ $db_field }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Import Data
    </button>
</form>
```

into my database table csv_data, where i store the csv files and data. it works fine, and the data is stored as it should be:

[image]

But when trying to import the file to my item table:

[image]

I get the error: "Undefined index: title"
With the following exception:
[image]

Var_dump($item) gives me the following:

```
{ ["fillable"]=> array(13) { 
[0]=> string(5) "title" 
[1]=> string(11) "item_number" 
[2]=> string(3) "ean" 
[3]=> string(6) "active" 
[4]=> string(5) "price" 
[5]=> string(10) "cost_price" 
[6]=> string(11) "offer_price" 
[7]=> string(6) "teaser" 
[8]=> string(11) "description" 
[9]=> string(9) "inventory" 
[10]=> string(5) "image" 
[11]=> string(8) "brand_id" 
[12]=> string(11) "category_id" }
```

Can any of you see what i am missing? i cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: It means $row doesn't have title. var_dump($row) to see what is the data.

Comment: Var_dump($row) throws me this : array(13) { [0]=> string(5) "title" [1]=> string(11) "item_number" [2]=> string(3) "ean" [3]=> string(6) "active" [4]=> string(5) "price" [5]=> string(10) "cost_price" [6]=> string(11) "offer_price" [7]=> string(6) "teaser" [8]=> string(11) "description" [9]=> string(9) "inventory" [10]=> string(5) "image" [11]=> string(8) "brand_id" [12]=> string(11) "category_id" } - as far as i can see, the title is my first index.

Comment: So this shows the titles. Remove this row from the array, and try again. This time you will get the first line of data without any key.

Comment: @BülentAkgül I am not sure what you mean here, can you explain where and what to remove? sorry.

Comment: See my answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is too complex. I googled "php csv to associative array" and found this code, which looks fairly clear.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file)); 
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) { 
   $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a); 
}); 
array_shift($csv);
```

https://medium.com/@czmole/php-convert-csv-to-associative-arrays-b82b9b4d4412

Comment: I cant get that to work, i am using this method since it should be able to choose from headers set specificly from a dropdown in a gui. i cannot see how i should be able to refactor my code down to anything like that without loosing functionality? perhabs you can show me? i would love to see it, if it in fact can give me a similar result